# Android Paging Library | Stop loading more data temporary

Tags: android, paging, android-architecture-components

I'm using Android Paging Library with Retrofit and Realm. I want to disable loading more data in a specific condition. And then enable loading more data back in normal condition.

Answer (score 0):

How often do you expect to flip the ability to load?

Are you trying to prevent loading from network into Realm or prevent loading from cached data in Realm?

There isn't a way (yet) to prevent item accesses from triggering loads, but you can return `MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = true)` in `RemoteMediator` if you're trying to prevent network loading. If you're trying to prevent loading from Realm, you could return an empty page with `null` `prevKey for` PREPEND`or`null nextKey`for`APPEND`. When you're ready to start loading again, all you need to do is call` PagingSource.invalidate()`(for db)`or PagingDataAdapter.refresh()` (for remote) to throw away the existing snapshot state. This is one method, but not practical if you expect to flip the loading state extremely often.

If you do go this route, you'll also need to implement `PagingSource.getRefreshKey(state: PagingState)` to allow `PagingSource` to reload items from where the position in the list the user is correct viewing.

For position-keyed PagingSource, which is typical when paging from a DB like Realm, a simple implementation for `getRefreshKey` might look like:

`PagingSource.getRefreshKey(state: PagingState) = state.anchorPosition`

I'd be interested to hear more about your use-case and if a more valid approach would be to allow disabling loading directly from item access, feel free to file a feature request here detailing your use-case a bit more: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=413106&template=1096385

Comment: I have a use-case where I want to translate items in my list. With each translation, an invalidation needs to be done which in turn triggers the `onItemAtEndLoaded` method (I'm still on Paging2). I'd like a way to invalidate local only so it doesn't perform unnecessary server requests with each translation. I can't figure a way to do it without violating the Paging contract thus breaking the functionality. My current hacky solution so the user doesn't see the load more UI is to just hide it if invalidation is triggered by a translation.

Comment: In Paging2, the `BoundaryCallback` is just a dumb callback as we never tracked or supported the concept of `LoadState` in that version. Unfortunately, you'll need to migrate to Paging3 or hook that tracking up yourself.

In Paging3, remote state is tracked separately from PagingSource state, invalidation never resets remote state. After returning `MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = true)`, Paging will never request another remote load until that bit is reset via `.refresh()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup your own loadmore adapter then change loadState, if **endOfPaginationReached** is **true** paging will hide the loadmore ui and stop loadmore function, Vice versa

```
loadmoreAdapter.loadState = LoadState.NotLoading(endOfPaginationReached = true)
```